# Paypal API refund a captured authorization

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I'm using the Paypal API to do authorize and capture, I can easily authorize, capture and void payments.

the problem is once a payment has been captured I can see no way to refund it since "RefundTransaction" tells me I can't refund this type of payment and "DoVoid" says the payment has already been captured.

### is there no way to refund a captured authorization via the API?

SOLVED
I was using the transaction ID for the authorization, it is necessary to use the transaction id received at the moment of capture.

Comment: RefundTransaction should work actually; are you sure you're putting in the correct parameters?

Comment: You are right, I wasn't aware that the transaction ID changed at the moment of capture which is why I got the error (facepalm). I'll update the question in case anyone runs into the same issue.

Comment: Glad you found out the issue :) please submit it as an answer and then accept it

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [RefundTransaction Message Request](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_RefundTransaction). But Im not sure, if it's a good style to authorize people by using PayPal payments - except you want to confirm their payment account.